# Checking in pom files to SCM using maven

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin, versions, maven-scm

Using the maven versions plugin I update the version numbers of the pom files :

```
versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0.2-SNAPSHOT
```

I then check in the pom files manually prior to performing a build. I don't think the versions plugin can check in files automatically? The maven releases plugin seems to offer functionalty for  checking in files using the 'prepare' goal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Are you asking how to configure scm in your project? Are you versioning for a release ?

Comment: @MikePatel ive updated my question, can the maven versions plugin check in files or do I need to use the relases plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No turns out its only poor mans SCM (stores a backup with the changes you make to the pom and allows you to revert to it).

Use the release plugin.